# Changing positionclass for toastr Notification

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, toastr

I am trying to change positionclass for my toast on div click.

> positionclass:is not changed to Bottom.?  what am i missing here?

and how to use

> toastr.optionsOverride = 'positionclass:toast-bottom-full-width';

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js")"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/toastr.js")"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/toastr.css" />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // show when page load
        toastr.info('Page Loaded!');

        $('#linkButton').click(function () {
            toastr.optionsOverride = 'positionclass:toast-bottom-full-width';
            // show when the button is clicked
            toastr.success('Click Button', 'ButtonClick', 'positionclass:toast-bottom-full-width');
        });

    });

</script>

<body>
    <div id ="linkButton" > click here</div>
</body>
```

**update 1**

**after debugging i have noticed that below getOptions method from toastr.js is overriding
'positionclass:toast-bottom-full-width' to 'toast-top-right'**

```
    function getOptions() {
        return $.extend({}, defaults, toastr.options);
    }
```

**update 2** Line 140 in toastr.js is not **successfully** extending m
optionsOverride in to options.??

```
        if (typeof (map.optionsOverride) !== 'undefined') {
            options = $.extend(options, map.optionsOverride);
            iconClass = map.optionsOverride.iconClass || iconClass;
        }
```

**update 3**
Postion issue has been fixed but I have to mention position class 3 times as below. I am sure there is a less noisy way to achieve this.

```
$('#linkButton').click(function () {

    toastr.optionsOverride = 'positionclass = "toast-bottom-full-width"';
    toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-full-width';
     //show when the button is clicked
    toastr.success('Click Button', 'ButtonClick', 'positionclass = "toast-bottom-full-width"');
});
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just set it like this, as shown in the toastr demo: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/
or this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6W9URNyyp2ItO4aUWzBB

```
toastr.options = {
  "debug": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width",
  "onclick": null,
  "fadeIn": 300,
  "fadeOut": 1000,
  "timeOut": 5000,
  "extendedTimeOut": 1000
}
```

Comment: Thanks @John. I figured out from given examples For some reasons i need to set it 2 times to make it work. Thank you for awesome library

Comment: @JohnPapa Can you explain where to put this? I have tried putting in my document onready, and also right before my call to toastr.warning. It doesn't seem to take. BTW I am just trying to change the showDuration so my options look like this:  `toastr.options = {
                "showDuration": "20000",
            }`

Comment: Version `2.0.2` has an issue where `positionClass` is not respected in all cases: [See the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/issues/156). It is fixed in `2.0.3`, but at the time of me writing this comment, there is no `2.0.3` release yet.

Comment: Correct, this has been fixed in what will be the next point release 2.0.3. Should be out soon or you can grab from github now.

Comment: In fact, toastr 2.0.3 is now released on bower, nuget and soon on cdnjs

Comment: There is a mistake: instead of ":" it needs to be "=". I tried to edit the post, but it needed to have at least 6 characters...

Answer (score 9):

it's a easy simple steps to change the position......see in below..

first declare the position class before showing the message.

EX: `toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';`

Then show your message as below:

`Command:`toastr"success"

Hope it with work well....Thanks

I just used it in my Laravel project.... I will put my code here if you understand it....

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    @if (Session::has('success'))

        toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';
        toastr.success("{{ Session::get('success') }}");

    @endif


</script>
```

[toastr notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3JAi.jpg)

Comment: For top left: `toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-top-left";`

Answer (score 7):

Ya there's definately a bug here...

For example.  Setting the options is a bit sticky.  I set them dynamically right before call the toast type I want.  The first time, the options don't matter.  The next toast seem to pick up the options, and then the toast after that won't change.

For example

```
var logger = app.mainModule.factory('logger', ['$log', function ($log) {

var error = function (msg, data, showtoast) {

    if (showtoast) {
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "debug": false,
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width",
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "300000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
        };
        toastr.error(msg);
    }
    $log.error(msg, data);
};
var info = function (msg, data, showtoast) {

    if (showtoast) {
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "debug": false,
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "300000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
        };
        toastr.info(msg);
    }
    $log.info(msg, data);
};
var warning = function (msg, data, showtoast) {

    if (showtoast) {
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": false,
            "debug": false,
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "5000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
        };
        toastr.warning(msg);
    }
    $log.warning(msg, data);
};

var success = function (msg, data, showtoast) {

    if (showtoast) {
        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": false,
            "debug": false,
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "5000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
        };

        toastr.success(msg);
    }
    $log.info(msg, data);
};


var logger = {
    success: success,
    error: error,
    info: info,
    warning: warning

};
return logger;
}]);
```

Comment: I'm having this issue too. LMK if you figured it out.

Comment: My issue was that the top container holds all toasts. If they differ in style, then the first one rules. Calling toastr.remove() will clear everything immediately and reset the positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find version 2.0.3!  The latest version is 1.4.1 [see this](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr/releases)

I ended up changing the hardcoded value for positionClass in 'angular-toastr.tpls.js'

Now it is centering correctly!

Answer (score 1):

In my case position is not working becuase I am calling the toast before the options property:

Before

```
toastr["info"]("Testing Toast")

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
```

After

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}

toastr["info"]("Testing Toast")
```