# Best way to create user notifications on webpage in ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

tl:dr -> User notification system on website. Can you avoid the need to call a javascript script to render notifications after ajax loads? (a base view that calls it would work, but there are no base views afaik)

I am looking for a way to add a User Notification System to my website. Such system would be responsible for displaying messages like 'Import success', 'Import failed', 'Session timed out' etc.

I know similar questions have been answered before, but here's my question:

- How should I do it to get as close as possible to having the notifications display themselves as soon as possible after being put to TempData? Having them rendered on _layout page would work, but only for requests that ask for whole page. What about loading only parts of website through ajax -> can I avoid having to write JS script in ajax callbacks or partial views?
  I am looking for something to prevent writing multiple calls to same function.

Answer (score 0):

[Toastr](http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/) is your notification Friend. [Demo Page](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

you can install it from [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/toastr)  Install-Package toastr

See my [SO question -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273355/changing-positionclass-for-toastr-notification)  for reference